# Not able to send values to the input box using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to launch a simple application and try to send a strings to input box. But when I try to do that, I am getting **no such element: Unable to locate element: method":"xpath","selector":"//input"}**. But it's a simple DOM with no complex structure. Can someone help me with this?

```
package selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SeleniumTest {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            //Creating a driver object referencing WebDriver interface
            WebDriver driver;
            
            //Setting webdriver.gecko.driver property
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "E:\\chromedriver.exe");
            
            //Instantiating driver object and launching browser
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            
            //Using get() method to open a webpage
            driver.get("https://todomvc.com/examples/angular2/");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input")).sendKeys("amazon");
            //Closing the browser
            driver.quit();
     
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with **explicit wait :**

> Explicit waits are available to Selenium clients for imperative,
> procedural languages. They allow your code to halt program execution,
> or freeze the thread, until the condition you pass it resolves. The
> condition is called with a certain frequency until the timeout of the
> wait is elapsed. This means that for as long as the condition returns
> a falsy value, it will keep trying and waiting.

**code  :**

```
driver.get("https://todomvc.com/examples/angular2/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input"))).sendKeys("Amazon");
```

read more about explicit wait [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/)